# Transact-SQL - number rows until condition met

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, reset, row-number

I'm trying to generate the numbers in the "x" column considering the values in field "eq", in a way that it should assign a number for every record until it meets the value "1", and the next row should reset and start counting again. I've tried with `row_number`, but the problem is that I only have ones and zeros in the column I need to evaluate, and the cases I've seen using `row_number` were using growing values in a column. Also tried with rank, but I haven't managed to make it work.

```
nInd    Fecha       Tipo    @Inicio     @contador_I  @Final     @contador_F eq  x
1       18/03/2002  I       18/03/2002  1            null       null        0   1
2       20/07/2002  F       18/03/2002  1            20/07/2002 1           1   2
3       19/08/2002  I       19/08/2002  2            20/07/2002 1           0   1
4       21/12/2002  F       19/08/2002  2            21/12/2002 2           1   2
5       17/03/2003  I       17/03/2003  3            21/12/2002 2           0   1
6       01/04/2003  I       17/03/2003  4            21/12/2002 2           0   2
7       07/04/2003  I       17/03/2003  5            21/12/2002 2           0   3
8       02/06/2003  F       17/03/2003  5            02/06/2003 3           0   4
9       31/07/2003  F       17/03/2003  5            31/07/2003 4           0   5
10      31/08/2003  F       17/03/2003  5            31/08/2003 5           1   6
11      01/09/2005  I       01/09/2005  6            31/08/2003 5           0   1
12      05/09/2005  I       01/09/2005  7            31/08/2003 5           0   2
13      31/12/2005  F       01/09/2005  7            31/12/2005 6           0   3
14      14/01/2006  F       01/09/2005  7            14/01/2006 7           1   4
```

Comment: Unless it adds value to your question chances are you shouldn't edit something BACK in that was deleted.  You'll find typing things such as "Good Day!" and "I really appreciate any help" will be looked down on.  It just gives extra reading and takes away from the actual question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited it, because at first time I put an image, but when saved it didn't show up. I guess it was a browser issue. So I put the same but as text.

Comment: No problem : ).  Unless someone is about to answer I should have an answer for you in a second.

Comment: Let me know how my answer does for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another solution available:

```
select 
  nind, eq, row_number() over (partition by s order by s) 
from (
  select 
    nind, eq, coalesce((
      select sum(eq) +1 from mytable pre where pre.nInd < mytable.nInd)
    ,1) s --this is the sum of eq!
  from mytable) g
```

The inner subquery creates `groups` sequentially for each occurrence of `1` in `eq`.  Then we can use `row_number() over partition` to get our counter.

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/KDAC73271) using Sql Server

Comment: you can also Update x to get groups and then select from the updated table.  That approach makes more sense, the above approach is an 'all in one solution'  if you want the other update/select just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have two answers here.  One is based off of the `ROW_NUMBER()` and the other is based off of what appears to be your index (`nInd`).  I wasn't sure if there would be a gap in your index so I made the `ROW_NUMBER()` as well.

My table format was as follows -

`myIndex int identity(1,1) NOT NULL 
number int NOT NULL`

**First one is `ROW_NUMBER()`...**

```
WITH rn AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myIndex) AS rn, COUNT(*) AS max 
                  FROM counting c GROUP BY c.myIndex, c.number)
,cte (myIndex, number, level, row) AS (

    SELECT r.myIndex, r.number, 1, r.rn + 1 FROM rn r WHERE r.rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r1.myIndex, r1.number, 
                       CASE WHEN r1.number = 0 AND r2.number = 1 THEN 1
                                                                 ELSE c.level + 1
                       END,
                       row + 1
    FROM cte c 
        JOIN rn r1 
            ON c.row = r1.rn
        JOIN rn r2
            ON c.row - 1 = r2.rn
    )

SELECT c.myIndex, c.number, c.level FROM cte c OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Now the index...**

```
WITH cte (myIndex, number, level) AS (

    SELECT c.myIndex + 1, c.number, 1 FROM counting c WHERE c.myIndex = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c1.myIndex + 1, c1.number, 
                           CASE WHEN c1.number = 0 AND c2.number = 1    THEN 1
                                                                        ELSE c.level + 1
                           END
    FROM cte c 
        JOIN counting c1
            ON c.myIndex = c1.myIndex
        JOIN counting c2
            ON c.myIndex - 1 = c2.myIndex
    )

SELECT c.myIndex - 1 AS myIndex, c.number, c.level FROM cte c OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: This is beautiful! Yes, my index is nInd, so I'll use the second one, but both methods work like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting. Works good in some cases, but if there are more than 100 rows I got this error: "The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion".

Comment: @MRamL right. Forgot about that since I never hit the max in my own queries. Put 'OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)' at the end (after the 'from cte')

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I have now is via using

```
Cursor
```

I know if there is another solution without cursor it will be better for performance aspects

here is a quick demo of my solution:

```
  -- Create DBTest
  use master
  Go
  Create Database DBTest
  Go
  use DBTest
  GO
  -- Create table
  Create table Tabletest
  (nInd    int , eq  int)
  Go
  -- insert dummy data
  insert into Tabletest (nInd,eq) 
  values    (1,0),
            (2,1),
            (3,0),
            (4,1),
            (5,0),
            (6,0),
            (7,0),
            (8,0),
            (9,1),
            (8,0),
            (9,1)



  Create table #Tabletest (nInd int ,eq int ,x int )
  go

  DECLARE  @nInd int , @eq int , @x int
  set @x = 1
  DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
  SELECT nInd , eq
  FROM Tabletest  
  order by nInd

  OPEN db_cursor   
  FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nInd , @eq   

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
  BEGIN   

   if (@eq = 0) 
     begin

            insert into #Tabletest (nInd ,eq  ,x) values (@nInd , @eq , @x)
            set @x = @x +1
     end 
     else if (@eq = 1)
     begin
            insert into #Tabletest (nInd ,eq  ,x) values (@nInd , @eq , @x)
            set @x = 1
     end

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nInd , @eq   

  END   

  CLOSE db_cursor   
  DEALLOCATE db_cursor


  select * from #Tabletest
```

The end result set will be as following:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But It's already implemented with a cursor in a stored procedure. I'm trying to optimize it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this a slightly different way (which might not be true, but eliminates the need for cursors of recursive CTEs), it looks like you building ordered groups within your dataset.  So, start by finding those groups, then determining the ordering of each of them.

The real key is to determine the rules to find the correcting grouping.  Based on your description and comments, I'm guessing the grouping is from the start (ordered by the `nInd` column) ending at each row with and `eq` value of `1`, so you can do something like:

```
;with ends(nInd, ord) as (
    --Find the ending row for each set
    SELECT nInd, row_number() over(order by nInd)
    FROM mytable
    WHERE eq=1
), ranges(sInd, eInd) as (
    --Find the previous ending row for each ending row, forming a range for the group
    SELECT coalesce(s.nInd,0), e.nInd
    FROM ends s
        right join ends e on s.ord=e.ord-1
)
```

Then, using these group ranges, you can find the final ordering of each:

```
select t.nInd, t.Fecha, t.eq
    ,[x] = row_number() over(partition by sInd order by nInd)
from ranges r
    join mytable t on r.sInd < t.nInd
                    and t.nInd <= r.eInd
order by t.nInd
```